# Benefit of IoC container in MVVMLight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, ioc-container

What is the benefit of IoC container in MVVM Light? What is the benefit of the ViewModelLocator? Why not instantiating the view-models directly in the XAML file like below?

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <!-- Other user control elements here -->

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Sounds like: Please explain me the IoC container and the ViewModelLocator. Please add more information on what your comparison is. The benefit from x instead of y would have some chance of getting an answer.

Comment: As I already explained, I can instantiate the view-model directly in XAML like in the code snipped above. Why should I use a ViewModelLocator and IoC instead? What is the benefit?

Answer (score 5):

Instantiating the view model in Xaml is absolutely fine, but there are a few things to take in to account...

- When you use Xaml for the view model, the VM constructor is called during the `InitializeComponent` method of the main window.  It means the VM will be created on the UI thread.  Some developers like that, others do not.
- Also when you use Xaml, it's like 'hard-coding' the VM and this defeats the late binding and module discovery that plays an integral role in large composite applications
- Somewhat related to the previous point, some teams like to decouple everything and use a configuration file to tell which vm should be instantiated.  This approach is especially useful if you want to do isolation testing.

For small, one-off WPF applications that want to use MVVM, the Xaml approach is fine; but as the app matures, eventually a more industrial strength approach will be called for.  And that's where the IoC container is essential.